# MS Access 2010 employee availability

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have built a database for our 700 existing consultants.

I'm recording their availability, or more accurately their lack of, in a table with 5 fields.

Primary Key, ConsultantID, BusyStart, BusyEnd, BusyType.

My main form selects the ConsultantID, and has a text box for the EventDate.

EventDate works as using

=IIf([EventDate] Between [TrainerBusy Subform].[Form]![BusyStart] And [TrainerBusy Subform].[Form]![BusyEnd],"yes","no")

But it only works for the first record displayed in the sub form.

I've made a few attempts to use vba to go through all of the records in the subform, and I think I need For Each to work through the records, +1 to a variable for each "yes" and then give a final "yes" or "no" if that variable is >0.

Am I totally down a rabbit hole here or is this the right idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is EventDate just one date? I'm assuming that you have an event start and an event end and you want to make sure there's no overlap. If your situation is different, you'll have to adjust the code to account for that.

Instead of trying to read the subform, read the data that supplies the subform.

My form has a combobox for ConsultantID, a textbox for EventStart, a textbox for EventEnd, and finally a textbox to display if the event is OK for that consultant.

I use the change events of the EventStart and EventEnd textboxes to call another procedure that updates the "status" textbox.

```
Private Sub tbxEventEnd_AfterUpdate()

    If IsDate(Me.tbxEventStart.Value) And IsDate(Me.tbxEventEnd.Value) Then
        PopulateIsOK
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub tbxEventStart_AfterUpdate()

    If IsDate(Me.tbxEventStart.Value) And IsDate(Me.tbxEventEnd.Value) Then
        PopulateIsOK
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateIsOK()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim aSql(1 To 5) As String

    aSql(1) = "SELECT  SUM(SWITCH ( ( BusyStart < #" & Me.tbxEventStart.Value & "# AND Busyend < #" & Me.tbxEventStart.Value & "#)"
    aSql(2) = "OR ( BusyStart >= #" & Me.tbxEventStart.Value & "# AND BusyStart > #" & Me.tbxEventEnd.Value & "#) , 0, True, 1"
    aSql(3) = ")) As StartCheck"
    aSql(4) = "FROM tblBusy WHERE ConsultantID = " & Me.cbxConsultantID.Value

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = cn.Execute(Join(aSql, Space(1)))

    If rs.Fields(0).Value = 0 Then
        Me.tbxIsEventOK.Value = "Yes"
    Else
        Me.tbxIsEventOK.Value = "No"
    End If

End Sub
```

The recordset sums the results - a zero if there is no conflict and a one if there is a conflict. If the sum is zero, none of the records conflict and Yes is written to the textbox.

You need some more error checking, for instance, to make sure there is a ConsultantID selected.